# Java 7 / 8 in Android?

Tags: java, android

Android is great mobile platform, it uses Java (for a good reason) a really popular programming language. 
But the Java language is evolving, moving forward, the version 7 with small language improvements has some years and the next year it comes the version 8 with the awaited lambdas.

My question is: Will Android run Java 7 or 8 or take some of their constructs?

UPDATE: Just for non believers: In Android Kitkat 4.4 we can use Java 7 goodies: ARM, switch over strings, diamond,etc. Yeah! 
I hope that it will not take so longer to get lambdas and Java 8 features

Comment: Seeing as we aren't the Android developers, we don't know and cannot answer you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android works today with Java 7, according to the tools team, though I have not tried it personally just yet. By this, I mean that you can compile an Android project with a Java 7 compiler, and the build tools will accept the Java 7 compiler output. AFAIK, there was only one new bytecode added (`invokedynamic`, or something like that), which is for interpreters, not the `javac` compiler.

Since Java 8 does not exist in final form, and since Google does not tend to give out future details like this (particularly given in-flight litigation), you will know when the rest of us know, sometime after Java 8 ships.

Comment: Do you mean all Java 7 structures like `java.awt.Point` are in Android somewhere, or that the Java 7 Runtime somehow works on Android? I'm confused by the statement "Android works with Java 7"

Comment: @WilliamMorrison: Neither. Sorry, I mean that a Java 7 compiler output will work with the build tools to create an APK. Given the in-flight litigation, I will be surprised if Java 7 classes are added to Android any time soon (if ever). Android has its own runtime (Dalvik VM).

Comment: So can I use features like try with resources in Android?

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the clarification. And for all the times your posts have helped in the past. +1

Comment: @NestorHernandezLoli: "try with resources" requires that the resources implement `AutoCloseable`, which does not exist in Android's class library: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html